# Indexing three columns differently

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I have the following two SQLs running constantly on big sets of data:

```
SELECT * FROM table t WHERE (deleted = 1 OR blocked = 1) AND active = 1;

SELECT * FROM table t WHERE active = 1 AND deleted = 0 AND blocked = 0;
```

The table right now has only the primary key on ID - what indexes should I add to improve the performance of those queries? (right now they take 3 minutes for about a million records).

I've been thinking about indexing:

```
(deleted, active)
(blocked, active)
(active, deleted, blocked)
```

I guess this would solve the issue, but isnt it too much indexes? How does mysql table behave when it has a lot of indexes?

Comment: `(active, deleted, blocked)` should do the job.

Comment: Not really, because how could it index deleted first, and active second?

Comment: I think it really depends on data distribution you have on 'active', 'blocked' and 'deleted' records. How is the active/total ratio? Did you try to add only an 'active' index?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - more indexes increase the size of the DB. Almost always(unless you have an algorithm problem) to improve speed - you use more memory(space.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your real goal.

- Are the queries interfering with other activity, and you need them to be less intrusive?  If so, I would walk through the table in chunks of 1K rows, using `id`.  [Chunking discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).
- Are you in a hurry to find something to work on?  I assume you take some action when the query finds some rows with those flags.  If so, I would add `AND id > $where_left_off ORDER BY id LIMIT 1`, work on the one.  [Pagination discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

Here's a 3rd approach:

```
INDEX(active, deleted, blocked, id) -- Active must be first; id must be last

SELECT a.*
    FROM table a
    JOIN table b  ON a.id = b.id
    WHERE b.active = 1
      AND b.deleted = b.blocked;
```

It will efficiently gather data for both queries in a single pass.  (Change the `WHERE` if that is not convenient.)  The `JOIN` has this effect:  Using `b`, only part of the new `INDEX` is scanned (the part with `active=1`), then the rest of the data is looked up (`a`).

If you are "processing" the found rows, I suggest you add a `LIMIT`, else your client might choke on too large a list in the rare case of having lots of rows.